# Add default columns in model migration

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I just want to ask if it is possible to add my default columns when I run the command: "php artisan make: model -m" just like created_at and updated_at are automatically added in the table.

I expect the following columns will be automatically added when I migrate it:
created_by
updated_by
posted_by
posted_at
approved_by
approved_at
etc...

Answer (score 0):

The class responsible for generating the migrations is [`Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/MigrationCreator.php). You could create a class which inherits from this class and overwrites the `stubPath()` or the `getStub()` method, and then put your version into the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container).

Or you could [create you own artisan command](https://medium.com/@devlob/laravel-crud-generators-614caddf8bea) to have more flexibility, which is what I usually do.